# mysqldump with wrong vowels - search and replace?

Tags: replace, typo3

i have a mysqldump from the customer with wrong vowels.
It is a backup, and i do not get a new one.

> eg instead of ü there is Ã¼, instead of ö there is Ã¶.

To solve this, can i make search and replace in notepad? Or can i damage other tables than tt_content or pages with a global search and replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by export and import with different charset configuration.
Just import your existing mysql dump at your local development server and try export/import as follow.
Create a new mysql dump and try some settings like:

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset --skip-extended-insert --skip-add-drop-table --no-create-info -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] > [MYSQLDUMNAME].sql
```

Import the new created mysql dump with settings like:

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] < [MYSQLDUMNAME].sql
```

You will need some tests, to find out the correct transformation (latin1,utf8).

If you have a mix of correct and incorrect chars in your mysql dump, you will probably exclude such tables, and import them separately like:

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset --skip-extended-insert --add-drop-table --ignore-table=[DBNAME].[TABLENAME] -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] > [MYSQLDUMNAME].sql
```

Replace [USERNAME],[DBNAME],[TABLENAME],[MYSQLDUMNAME] with your values.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly caused by wrong encoding settings used to dump the backup (like communicating with the server in utf-8 when database is in cp-1252). If you can get the settings used to create it, you can import it on your local machine with the same settings correctly and create a new dump with correct settings to fix it.

You can attempt to fix it with search replace, but you will probably miss a lot of symbols, unless it is really small dump and you can actually check it completely by hand afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following TYPO3Wiki entry. Here are some method described how to convert the Data into utf8:

https://wiki.typo3.org/UTF-8_support#Possibility_2